# Raspberry Pi 2: Using WiFi on BerryBoot

Tags: networking, wifi, berryboot

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2. I can not use WiFi while running Berryboot. I'm having issues in my Network Settings where I can only use Ethernet.

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose what might be wrong unless you provide some more information. Can you post the contents of /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf, and the make and model of your wifi adapter?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a USB Wireless Adapter, it more than likely isn't using it's required drivers that are enabled when completely booted. If you have a different adapter, try using it, otherwise it probably won't work.